# Direct3D9 Get D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS From IDirect3DDevice9

Tags: c++, directx, directx-9, direct3d9

Is there a way to retrieve all info that requires to re-build `D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS` from a created device?

In Direct3D11 `ID3D11DeviceContext` saves all this trouble, but how would you go and get all the necessary information to re-construct present parameters?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call [IDirect3DDevice9::GetSwapChain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/d3d9helper/nf-d3d9helper-idirect3ddevice9-getswapchain) to get an instance of IDirect3DSwapChain9 interface. Then call [GetPresentParameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/d3d9helper/nf-d3d9helper-idirect3dswapchain9-getpresentparameters) to get that structure.